# How do i show a not-equals operator for rules while setting up commerce shipping conditions?

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I am setting up my commerce shipping conditions and i need a NOT Equal operator so i can target all international countries. how can this be done?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose "=", then at the bottom of your condition, enable "negate".  It's just below where your screenshot is cut-off.

Comment: why couldnt they just make it an operator!?

Comment: While you only see three values for your condition, there are a ton of other values in other conditions in rules. It makes more sense to provide "negate" than to provide all opposing values.

Comment: fwiw, it isn't an operator b/c this is just the way Rules was built; good feedback to post to the Rules queue in a feature request, though the main idea is that Negate is useful in many other cases, so it was used here (and in generic conditions like "Data comparison" because it was already there.